# Clone clientdataset params

Tags: delphi, clone, tclientdataset

I clone master dataset that's have parameters list `date1` and `date2` to limits the records fetched from the db

```
cds_CVentes.CloneCursor(DMT.cds_Ventes, True);
```

i have Form1 DB-Aware attached to the master ClientDataSet
at run time i create form1 instance (form2)  Reassigning the datasource to the cloned dataset
when i edit the parameters in the cloned ClientDataSet changes reflected to the master ClientDataSet...

I'm wondering if i can bypass this behavior thanks...

Comment: Difficult to guess exactly what you're doing and what might be going wrong from this minimal description.  You might get more/better help if you post your TForm1 code (and that of Form2, unless it's genuinely just another instance of TForm1).

Comment: Have you tried changing filter instead of params?

Comment: Marcus Adams sorry for the delay in replay i will try to change the filter and provide more info ...